# CMake imported library behaviour

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I've a strange problem with CMake.

I'm importing Curl into my project, so I write for you a simplified summary of my CMakeLists.txt file.

> ADD_LIBRARY (libcurl **SHARED** IMPORTED)
>
> SET_PROPERTY(TARGET libcurl PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION
> ../lib/libcurl.lib)

When I run CMake it generates the project files for MS VC++ (also for Linux). Then into the project file I find a wrong reference to curl library (**libcurl-NOTFOUND**)!

If I change my code into static import:

> ADD_LIBRARY (libcurl **STATIC** IMPORTED)
>
> SET_PROPERTY(TARGET libcurl PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION
> ../lib/libcurl.lib)

I find the right reference to ../lib/libcurl.lib.

Do you have any idea why this happens?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello, Please let me know how the issue was resolved. I followed the below comment, but it is leading to much more errors.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For a shared library, the `IMPORTED_LOCATION` must point to the DLL, not the import lib. See the [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aIMPORTED_LOCATION). You might also want to set the [IMPORTED_IMPLIB](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aIMPORTED_IMPLIB) property.

BTW, CMake also has a [find package](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#module%3aFindCURL) for Curl; perhaps you could use that?

Comment: I have added the DLL to the IMPORTED_LOCATION.Also added the LIB with IMPORTED_IMPLIB But that is not resolving the error for the shared library linking.

Comment: cmake will also need to see IMPORTED_IMPLIB if you claim your library is 'SHARED' in add_library. Common practice in Find*.cmake modules seems to be to declare it 'UNKNOWN' to avoid the issue.

Comment: Also, the *path* provided to `IMPORTED_LOCATION` must be a **full** path, not a relative one.

Comment: It should be noted that cmake's doc on [add_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_library.html) has zero references to `IMPORTED_IMPLIB`.

Comment: @RAM Zero references by full name. It does however tell you to look at *all* the `IMPORTED_*` properties for configuring the target, and just mentions the most important one (and it does say it must point to the *main* library file). Note that `IMPORTED_IMPLIB` is platform-specific, just like e.g. `IMPORTED_SONAME`. All the other `IMPORTED_*` properties may or may not be relevant, based on a given use case. It makes more sense for the docs to just point you to them all (as they do) instead of mentioning them all individually.

Comment: @AngewisnolongerproudofSO mentioning IMPORTED_* means nothing as represent about two dozen different vars, some of which are irrelevant. It also doesn't sound right to downplay support for Windows libraries as "platform-specific" because all libs are platform specific and Windows is one of the most popular target platforms, if not the most popular.