# Force CMake to use the full library path

Tags: linux, linker, cmake

I have the following problem. I have a separate {bin,lib,include} tree on my Linux machine where CMake and all my libraries I need for my development work are installed. But only the PATH environment variable is set to this bin directory and for several reason I can not set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. All programs inside this tree are build using RPATHs. The CMake 3.3.1 I am using is also inside this tree.

Now the problem I want to compile a program using libcurl and set up the following CMakeLists.txt

```
PROJECT(EXAMPLE)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8) 
SET(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH FALSE)
FIND_PACKAGE(CURL REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenSSL REQUIRED) 
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
SET(LIBS ${CURL_LIBRARIES} ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}) 

ADD_EXECUTABLE(curl_ex src/curl_ex.c)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(curl_ex ${LIBS})
```

When I now run CMake the curl and the OpenSSL setup out of my personal software tree is found due to the fact that it resides inside the same prefix as CMake.

But when I build the project using `make VERBOSE=1` I see the following linking command:

```
gcc CMakeFiles/curl_ex.dir/src/curl_ex.c.o  -o curl_ex -rdynamic -lcurl -lssl -lcrypto
```

and the build executable refers to the system-wide installed curl and openssl libraries instead of the one cmake found during the configuration.

How can I force CMake to use the libraries it found when it performs the linking?

Comment: This may be related to the same problem described in policy [`CMP0060`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/policy/CMP0060.html). It mainly recommends to use ["IMPORTED library targets"](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets) where you can give full paths in `IMPORTED_LOCATION` or to call `cmake_policy(SET CMP0060 NEW)` (since the default is `OLD`).

Comment: See [CMake: TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES with full path libraries](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2014-September/058647.html). And if you really want to force it `target_link_libraries(curl_ex PRIVATE "-l$<JOIN:${LIBS}, -l>")` (see [here](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2014-June/057767.html)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

I was able to reproduce your problem - even without having the exact same environment - and found two possible solutions:

1. You set policy [`CMP0060`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/policy/CMP0060.html) to `NEW`

   ```
   cmake_policy(SET CMP0060 NEW)
   ```

   > The NEW behavior for this policy is to link libraries by full path even if they are in implicit link directories.
2. You can create a intermediate imported library and use `IMPORTED_LOCATION` (see [[CMake] TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES with full path libraries](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2014-September/058647.html))

   ```
   add_library(curl UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
   set_property(TARGET curl PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CURL_LIBRARIES}")
   target_link_libraries(curl_ex curl)
   ```

   This worked for me, but according to [CMake imported library behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850736/cmake-imported-library-behaviour) you may need to also set `IMPORTED_IMPLIB`.

**Background**

Please check the setting of `CMAKE_PLATFORM_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES` because the paths listed there are taken as "implicit" search paths and full library paths are replaced accordingly (see [`cmComputeLinkInformation::CheckImplicitDirItem()`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmComputeLinkInformation.cxx#L1196) and [`UnixPaths.cmake`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Platform/UnixPaths.cmake#L85))

```
message("CMAKE_PLATFORM_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES: ${CMAKE_PLATFORM_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES}")
```

Comment: Thanks, the CMP0060 explains why my first workarounds only work with the newest CMake version.