# KDevelop4: Set environment variable when before CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, kdevelop, kdevelop4

Related to my other question here ([CMake: Force to use optional include and library path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156371/cmake-force-to-use-optional-include-and-library-path)), how do I set an environment variable in Kdevelop4 when debugging the project / executing CMake?

I need to set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH in order to give certain duplicate libraries installed in another path priority over libraries installed in /usr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not specific to Kdevelop, but you could change your `CMakeLists.txt` to include another CMake file, if it exists. This file would contain your ad-hoc configuration. For example :

```
# LocalConfig.cmake
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/opt/hhd/geos")

# CMakeLists.txt
include(LocalConfig.cmake OPTIONAL)

find_package(geos)
```