# Avoid automatically added "lib" prefix when using target_link_libraries

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to link a C++ project to the RCpp library; the file is called `Rcpp.so`, not the linux-default `libRcpp.so`. Furthermore, the library resides at the non-standard location `/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/libs`.

So I tried using a combination of `find_library` and `target_link_libraries`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project("R-Tests")

find_library(RCPP
    NAMES Rcpp.so
    HINTS /usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/libs
)
if (NOT RCPP)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find Rcpp - exiting.")
else()
    message("Found Rcpp: " ${RCPP})
endif()

# test target
add_executable(rcpptest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(rcpptest ${RCPP})
```

Configuring works fine, CMake outputs:

```
Found Rcpp: /usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
```

However, during build, CMake passes `-lRcpp` to the compiler, which causes the compilation to fail, since the library file is not named `libRcpp.so` but instead `Rcpp.so`:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable rcpptest
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/rcpptest.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
c++     CMakeFiles/rcpptest.dir/main.cpp.o  -o rcpptest  -L/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/libs -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/libs -lRcpp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lRcpp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Since the `message` line prints the full path to the `Rcpp.so` file just fine, is there any way to let `target_link_libraries` just add this path to the compiler instead of a combination of `-L` and `-l`?

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165270/force-cmake-to-use-the-full-library-path), this should be disabled by adding `cmake_policy(SET CMP0060 NEW)`; however, I can't see any change in the behavior of CMake if I set this to `NEW` or `OLD`.

Comment: Maybe you can add the library using [the `LINK_LIBRARIES` property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LINK_LIBRARIES.html) directly on the `rcpptest` target?

Comment: Anyway, this must be a common problem, have you tried to search for solutions using your favorite search engine? I doubt there isn't duplicate here on SO.

Comment: I searched in the doc, on SO and other sources and haven't found any.

Comment: Nvm, I found somewhat of a duplicate and edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have been bitten by the OLD (default) behavior of [CMP0060](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/policy/CMP0060.html), which converts absolute paths back to `-lfoo`.

Alternatively, define and use an IMPORTED target:

```
add_library(Rcpp SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET Rcpp PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so)
target_link_libraries(rcpptest Rcpp)
```

Comment: Would this also work if lives suddenly in a standard location on a different system?

Comment: Also, ``CMP0060`` doesn't seem to be the issue; I have updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: Good to know. You can combine the `IMPORTED` approach with the path produced by `find_package`.