# Create external module import files

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules

I am converting a project to stop using *Visual Studio Project Files* and switch to using `cmake`.

The project is already a few years old, and makes use of custom precompiled external libraries, located outside the code tree:

> src/
>     ... source tree ...
> externalLibs/
>     Python27/
>         include/
>             ... header files ...
>         libs/
>             python27.lib
>             python27_d.lib
> cmake/
>     Modules/
>         FindPython2.cmake

What I have done is add the directory `cmake/Modules`, and inside it the file `FindPython2.cmake`.

Then, I have created the `CMakeLists.txt` of one of the project components:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.17 )
project( ConnectorTests CXX )

include( ../../../../../global.cmake )

set( CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${ROOT_PATH}/cmake/Modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} )

message( "CMAKE_MODULE_PATH:" "${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}" )

find_package( Python2 REQUIRED )

add_executable( ConnectorTests pch.h pch.cpp Tests.cpp )

target_include_directories( ConnectorTests PRIVATE
  ../../Connector
  ../../MtoUtils
  "${Python2_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
)

target_link_libraries( ConnectorTests PRIVATE Python2 )
```

<sub>The above is just an excerpt with the relevant parts.</sub>

I include a global with the path definitions (`include( ../../../../../global.cmake`), I establish where to look for the modules (`set( CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${ROOT_PATH}/cmake/Modules"$ {CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} )`), and I use my custom module (`find_package( Python2 REQUIRED )`.

I've put a `message( )` to see if everything looks fine, and it shows me what I expect:

> CMAKE_MODULE_PATH: E:/cmake/Modules

My `FindPython2.cmake` module is this:

```
add_library( Python2 SHARED IMPORTED )

if( WIN32 )
  set_target_properties( Python2 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "${ROOT_PATH}/externalLibs/Python27/libs/python27.lib" )
  set_target_properties( Python2 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG "${ROOT_PATH}/externalLibs/Python27/libs/python27_d.lib" )
endif( )

set( Python2_FOUND ON )
set( Python2_Development_FOUND ON )
set( Python2_Development.Module_FOUND ON )
set( Python2_Development.Embed_FOUND ON )
set( Python2_INCLUDE_DIRS "${ROOT_PATH}/externalLibs/Python27/include" )
```

I generate the project without problems:

```
 cmake -B build -T v141, host = x86 -A win32
```

But when compiling:

```
 cmake --build build
```

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: no se puede abrir el archivo 'Python2-NOTFOUND.obj' [E:\Desarrollo\PATH\build\Test\ConnectorTests\ConnectorTests.vcxproj]

I'm using:

> cmake --version
> cmake version 3.17.20032601-MSVC_2

- What am I doing wrong ?
- How do I solve it ?

Comment: Spanish version: [Creación de archivos de importación de módulos externos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/384954/19610)

Comment: For a SHARED IMPORTED library its IMPORTED_LOCATION property should point to the `.dll` file, not to the `.lib` file. See that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850736/cmake-imported-library-behaviour.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thx, I look at it now.